# how to get the line after a certain mark?

Tags: python, regex

I have a large file, I want to extract the info after a certain line  `inserting results...` the file content is similar as below

```
...

inserting results...
['xxx']
...
inserting results...
['xxxs']
...
```

`...` represents other lines which don't contain `inserting results...` as contents.

my point is I just need the line which can have any form following the line `inserting results...`.

Here I should get`[['xxx'],['xxxs']]` as result.

Comment: If you have control over the software writing this file, you should consider modifying it to output a log file that can be more easily parsed, e.g. by outputting lines of JSON.

Comment: @a'r I appreciate your advice, do you mean output the wanted info as JSON? can you be more elaborate,  I thought regex is efficient enough.

Comment: If you have control of the source system, then you can output the data in a structured format, such as JSON. This is important as it not only makes your code simpler, but it removes the risk introduced by the current solutions that rely on the text 'inserting results...' to not change. It's not obvious - to a future maintainer of your system - that this text is crucial for part of the system to function, and so could be changed or removed.

Comment: @a'r Thanks a lot, I appreciate your explanation, you're right, it's a more reasonable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine flags `re.MULTILINE` and `re.DOTALL`. Then `^` and `$` means beginning/end of the line ([regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/uSmnpO/1)).

For example:

```
txt = '''
...
xxxxx
inserting results...
['xxx']
xxx
inserting results...
['xxxs']
...
'''

import re

print( re.findall(r'^inserting results.*?^(.*?)$', txt, flags=re.M|re.S) )
```

Prints:

```
["['xxx']", "['xxxs']"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, you can see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PG6EQW/1) and here is the workin snippet below:

```py
import re

txt = \
"""
xxxxx
inserting results...
['xxx']
xxx
inserting results...
['xxxs']
"""

x = re.findall("\[.*?\]", txt)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
["['xxx']", "['xxxs']"]
```

Comment: I think you haven't put  `xxxxx` as ['xxx'] into consideration.